# Equivalent of preg_match, that returns pretty (multidimensional) array

Tags: php, regex, multidimensional-array

is there some PHP function or library, which returns result of regex as pretty multidimensional array according to brackets in regular expression? This is, what I mean:

```
preg_match('/(n(e?)c)(o)/', 'neco', $vysl);
var_dump($vysl);
```

returns this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "neco"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "nec"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "e"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "o"
}
```

I would like to have output like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "neco"
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "nec"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "e"
  }
  [2]=>
  string(1) "o"
}
```

Every subexpression result is in expected (wanted) depth in this array.

Comment: `print_r()` instead of `vardump`?

Comment: There's no problem with var_dump, but with format of array returned by preg_match.

Comment: There's no such thing as a formatted array. Preg_match returns a normal array and the format you see is how vardump outputs arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question! There's no such thing built-in, you'll have to capture offsets of matches and for each match check if its offset is within some other's bounds: something that reminds me of the nested sets model:

```
function match_tree($re, $subject) {
    preg_match($re, $subject, $ms, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    $p = [(object)[]];

    foreach($ms as $m) {
        $m = (object) [
            'le'  => $m[1],
            'ri'  => $m[1] + strlen($m[0]) - 1,
            'str' => $m[0]];

        for($i = count($p) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            if(!$i || ($m->le >= $p[$i]->le && $m->le <= $p[$i]->ri)) {
                $p []= $m;
                $p[$i]->sub []= $m;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $p[0];
}
```

For example,

```
print_r(match_tree('/(n(e?)c)(o)(f(o(abc)))/', 'XnecofoabcY'));
```

returns

```
stdClass Object
(
    [sub] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [le] => 1
                    [ri] => 9
                    [str] => necofoabc
                    [sub] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [le] => 1
                                    [ri] => 3
                                    [str] => nec
                                    [sub] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [le] => 2
                                                    [ri] => 2
                                                    [str] => e
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [le] => 4
                                    [ri] => 4
                                    [str] => o
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [le] => 5
                                    [ri] => 9
                                    [str] => foabc
                                    [sub] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [le] => 6
                                                    [ri] => 9
                                                    [str] => oabc
                                                    [sub] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [le] => 7
                                                                    [ri] => 9
                                                                    [str] => abc
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Great! That is, what I want. Thanks. I think your code should be in PEAR. :-) (And respect to you. You write this code faster, than I grasp it... )